# How to make type inference work for a tuple with generic (on the example of array based queue)?

Tags: typescript, tuples

Imagine I have an interface for analytics object:

```ts
type Analytics = {
    identify: () => void;
    page: (title: string) => void;
    track: (eventName: string, props: object) => void;
}
```

And I want to implement some kind of queue that will collect all actions before we will be able to execute them. The queue looks as follows:

```js
const queue = [
    ['identify'],
    ['page', 'some title'],
    ['track', 'event 1', { a: 'a' }],
    ['track', 'event 2', { b: 'b' }]
];
```

First item is always a method name (`identify`, `page`, `track`) and the rest are method arguments from `Analytics` type.

Interface for the queue that came into my mind:

```ts
type QueueItem<T extends keyof Analytics> = [T, ...Parameters<Analytics[T]>]
```

Ok, let's try it:

```ts
const item1: QueueItem = ['track', 'some event', {}]
```

As a result I get a Typescript error: `Generic type 'QueueItem' requires 1 type argument(s)`.

What about explicit generic type if it can't be inferred automatically?

```ts
const item2: QueueItem<keyof Analytics> = ['track'] //  no error, although "track" method expects to receive two parameters
const item3: QueueItem<keyof Analytics> = ['track2'] //  error as there is no such method in Analytics
```

Not working as expected. Typescript thinks that type of items is `[keyof Analytics] | [keyof Analytics, string] | [keyof Analytics, string, object]` and it allows different combinations of method names (`identify`, `page`, `track`) and arguments like `['identify', 'some string', {}]`.

But will it work with a function? It will:

```ts
function func<T extends keyof Analytics>(method: T, ...args: Parameters<Analytics[T]>) {}

func('track') //  error, because track has 2 parameters
func('track', 'event', {}) //  no error
func('identify') //  no error
func('page', 'title') //  no error
func('page') //  error as we need to pass title
```

What should be changed in `QueueItem` type to make it work as expected (the same way as with function)?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgQwDYmASwMYGcoF4oDeAsAFBTlRoAmEc6AZiAFxQAUAlHgHxQBuA9tQDcpClDAIA5hBat0wJDKhZgAJzRxJnXDwHDRFNQgwBrWRF61gAOQQBbJSvWaANONX8wWFvwBGAKwgMYG1dQSoREgBfUlJQSCgARQBXCFSASWAIOwAeABUoCAAPLLgqHBMIEH56WEQUdGwefABtPLcAOi6ABQRVewgs1Swc+GRUTCw2gF0uadiSDH44FUosuwBGFhS0iEzsvCgWgHIjU2O3Y6x+B0LLOgvCKOmoAHpXqGAACzQcKn4IDg4PxgFAAO78VQmKBUVKffiFVQeVRQABEAHFaBB1BhPuBoMcdhl1scoKoIABHZJock4DZ4hJ9STJBx0VhYdio0hLFagtDrABM21SxOyOUq1VqYwak2aR1O-XOL3eUEAvBuAOR2oMDEci3MhvvxkpIvmiziZUVAHAaqIUipBgjhgAjyRgIGhLJ8IeI+gMhlhuctVvzsgBmYW7fa5CU1OrjRpYOUnM0C47Kj6qwCyOzrIVAEI6vtjoL8tQisMkMCbjOhlpQ4LGZdgFvRknBgmga83W-lbaVylBo1L6hMmqwrV9+FQWO0oF0OkzvFBev0rdiRtLh1M8rNOAQYiRSJ2MKwFcYTMdOCrM9nVG5fEEEMksNAzVAvnmoALvcvBquDy2jye5yXBYViPLuF7plm2rYsif6tse1BWGgjDnm8kEltecEARI0iPKc-KKKhl5QQiMGQlhx44RARHoWRKLvmC0BwBAEA2k63pYI6BEQEAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is when `T` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), `QueueItem<T>` produces a tuple-of-unions, when what you *want* is a union-of-tuples.  The tuple-of-unions allows mismatches between the method name and the parameter list.

In your generic function, the compiler can generally infer `T` to be a single key from `Analytics` and therefore the type `Parameters<Analytics[T]>` is exactly the type you expect.  There are situations where even that generic function will infer `T` to be a union, though, and then the same problem comes up:

```
const method = (["identify", "page", "track"] as const)[
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
// const method: "identify" | "page" | "track"
func(method); // <-- no error, but there is a 67% chance of a problem at runtime
```

---

As I said, you'd really like `QueueItem` to be a union of tuples; you want to consider each key `K` in `keyof Analytics` separately, calculate `QueueItem<K>` for that key, and then unite all the results.  In other words, you want to *distribute* `QueueItem<K>` across unions in `K`.  One way to do this is with [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
type QueueItem =
    keyof Analytics extends infer K ? K extends keyof Analytics ?
    [K, ...Parameters<Analytics[K]>]
    : never : never
/* type QueueItem = ["identify"] | ["page", string] | ["track", string, object] */
```

Unfortunately, distributive conditional types really only distribute over "naked" type parameters, so the above plays tricks with [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) to turn `keyof Analytics` into such a naked type parameter.

I prefer instead to use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each key `K in keyof Analytics` and then [index into it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) with `keyof Analytics` to get the desired union:

```
type QueueItem = {
    [K in keyof Analytics]: [K, ...Parameters<Analytics[K]>]
}[keyof Analytics]
/* type QueueItem = ["identify"] | ["page", string] | ["track", string, object] */
```

Either way works though.

---

You can verify that such a definition of `QueueItem` results in your desired behavior:

```
const item1: QueueItem = ['track', 'some event', {}] // okay
const item2: QueueItem = ['track'] // error
const item3: QueueItem = ['track2'] // error
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAggdgQwDYmASwMYGcoF4oDeAsAFBTlRoAmEc6AZiAFxQAUAlHgHxQBuA9tQDcpClDAIA5hBat0wJDKhZgAJzRxJnXDwHDRFNQgwBrWRF61gAOQQBbJSvWaANONX8wWFvwBGAKwgMYG1dQSoREgBfUlJQSCgARQBXCFSASWAIOwARNBU8A3ITCBB+elhEFHRsKAgADyy4KhwNeghVKABpKAB+brrG2haoErKK+GRUTBxeoqgAbS63ADo1gAUEVXsILNUsAB5J6pmlgF0uM-mWOAsOqBu71VIAegAqKHjoFLSITOy8gV8AsAETUKxoRggs5QAA+ixBEmkILcTg0khh8NBRlMKOUanRbj8gWCMLeL1iJDi4G+qQyWTseEI8yWlDgo1K5UqUxqWDOLCWqw2Wx2e0Ox2m2HOl1IUQWYy5Et5VxI70+NKSdL+DKZoPBdEhIGhcIRSIgeLRmkxCJxJgtBNcUGJQWAZIpVI9GH4cAKaAZAEYWD96dldQByW1htxhrD8Bx1Sx0KOEKIwl4vJ0mBAgUhen3ASgMgBMQa1-0ZwIj21MYbTGY6HmeJDzvoZAGZS79y+HbUXa1B03VVI3KZT6Mk4ME0N6oOPJwcACqDJojBUTKqSrBcVgOYAAC34VBYC6FKy2km8UE2213HXFG95CwXF04BCgMWb3oKu4PVCZrD1GgDShNxESkc1QNtY0EBwFsQgWABZBB9xWegkH4fhVFYJCUO2Zo4w4KAPjbdgzkiQc4KgH9DxYMEgIYI0TTA5EmKg0g5wwHddl-dghAHDMDgAWkEqA4H4IdGwAQlIIA)

Comment: Thank you very much for so detailed answer. I'd even say a mini-lecture I also prefer the second variant, looks simpler